# Oops! I forgot the clamps when I fixed my sprinklers!

Tags: sprinkler-system

For the first time ever, I fixed a broken sprinkler pipe that a root had pushed through. After it was all put together and re-buried, I realized that I forgot to use clamps on the patch. I did test the line before I buried it and saw no leaks. Am I going to regret not going back in and clamping?

Comment: You'll only regret not going back in and putting the clamps on if you don't want leaks to form later.

Answer (score 1):

If the repair was done inline with the pipe and pipe is fully seated on both side then it will probably never fail but might leak over time.  But if the pipe is not fully seated onto the barbs on each end or the repair was done on an end then you have a high chance for a future failure.

If the pipe is on a sprinkler zone, and not part of the supply, then your risks are further reduced.

Regardless of all these things,be nice to yourself and the future home owner.  Go buy some stainless steel clamps then dig up the probably shallow pipe, unscrew the clamp all the way, and place them over the pipe without having to remove the pipe from the fitting like for pinch clamps.  A special trip to buy the clamps should take longer than the digging, installation and backfill combined.